# Django Crispy Forms - Initial value not being set

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

First time asking for help on this one.   I am trying to use crispy forms to improve the layouts on my page.  However, when I changed a working page from plain Django form to use Crispy forms the initial value is no longer being set on the form

Forms.Py

```
    def __init__(self, client_, *args, ** kwargs):
        super(RecurringEventForm, self).__init__(*args, ** kwargs)
        self.fields['client'].initial = client_

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-inline'
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('recurring_label', css_class='form-control col-md-2 w-30'),
            Field('event_type', css_class='form-control col-md-2 w-25'),
            Field('carer', css_class='form-control col-md-2 w-25'),
            Row(
                Column('recurring_start_date', css_class='form-group col-md-2'),
                Column('recurring_end_date', css_class='form-group col-md-2'),
                css_class='form-row'
            ),
            Row(
                Column('event_start_time', css_class='form-group col-md-2'),
                Column('event_end_time', css_class='form-group col-md-2'),
                css_class='form-row'
            ),
            Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn-primary')
        )
```

HTML - that doesn't work

```
{% block content %}
<h1>Create Series</h1>
<br/><br/>

    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {% crispy form %}

        <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{% url 'manage_client_schedule' client_id %}">Cancel</a>

    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

when I use the same form definition with the below HTML it sets the initial value correctly

HTML - working

```
{% block content %}
<h1>Create Series</h1>
<br/><br/>

    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form.as_p }}

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{% url 'manage_client_schedule' client_id %}">Cancel</a>

    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

I can't find anything in Crispy documentation that explains why the Initial value is not being set - any help much appreciated!!

Comment: Not sure about which field you are talking exactly but most probably `client`. If so, this field is not included in the helper and thats why it is not part of the crispy output.

Comment: @Marco - that was exactly it.  Client is a Hidden Field in the Form definition so I hadn't included in the layout.   Thank You!